# Best way to sort multidimentional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have a multidimentional array

```
array = [];
array[0] = [1,3,8,4,9,5];
array[1] = [5,9,4,2,9,3,0];
array[2] = [5,2,6,1,3,8,4,9,5,17,2,9,3,0];
array[3] = [-1,0,20,6];
```

I want to sort it to get this result

```
[
       [-1,0,0,0,1,1],
       [2,2,2,3,3,3,3],
       [4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,8,8,9,9,9],
       [9,9,17,20]
]
```

I have defined this function that helped me get this result

```
Array.prototype.sort_multi = function()
{
    var arr = [];
    this.forEach(function(element_arr,index_arr,array_arr)
    {
        element_arr.forEach(function(element,index,array)
        {
            arr.push(element);
        });
    });
    arr.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b;});
    this.forEach(function(element_arr,index_arr,array_arr)
    {
        element_arr.forEach(function(element,index,array)
        {
            array_arr[index_arr][index] = arr.shift();
        });
    });
    return this;
}
```

My question is: is there a simple way to do this ? for example using the function `sort`, or a simple algorithm ... ?

Comment: Join it, sort it, chunk it into pieces of the original size

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A slightly simplified (and slightly more efficient) version of `sort_multi()`:

Basically what is happening here is:

1. The items in the original array are combined into one big array (for easy sorting)
2. We record the lengths of the original child arrays while joining
3. Sort the joined array numerically (as in the code you posted)
4. Split the sorted big array as per the lengths of the original child arrays
5. Return the result

Why this is more efficient than the original code:

1. The original code iterates through each child array element by element for joining. This is not needed since we have the natively implemented `concat()` for exactly that.
2. The original code again iterates element by element when splitting the joined/sorted array - Not needed since we have `splice()`.

---

```
Array.prototype.sort_multi = function() {
    var joined = [], lens = [], result = [];
    this.forEach(function(item) {
        joined = joined.concat(item);
        lens.push(item.length); // store the initial lengths
    });
    joined = joined.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b;}); // sort numerically
    lens.forEach(function(item) { // for each length in lens
        result.push(joined.splice(0, item));
    });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Actually, your code with the repeated `concat`s and `splice`s is much less efficient than the original code. Can you fix that?

Comment: @Bergi - How is it less efficient.. It concats once for each child array and splices once for each child array expected in the output. So if you have 4 child arrays, it concats 4 times and splices 4 times. Can it be reduced? [Note: The method is to be called only on the parent array containing child arrays]

Comment: Exactly. For 4 lists in the array, you create 4 `joined` arrays, and then do 4 `splice`s, where each of these operations needs to iterate the whole array. It has `O(n*n*m)` complexity while it could be `O(n*m)`

Comment: Can you please post the suggested improvement in a fiddle perhaps. Maybe even as an answer as it will be helpful to future visitors. I'm out of ideas as to how to reduce it further.

Comment: Ok, concat can take any number of params, so one call should suffice. Still we'll need 4 splices. Right?

Comment: No, just don't modify the array when getting the chunks back.